# Cloud SQL second generation - Unable to create failover

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've created a failover replica using Cloud SQL second generation, I had to delete it and create another one after a few hours, but it always prompts the following message:

```
"There is already an instance with that name."
```

I was using the same name of the failover that I deleted earlier, so I changed the name but another error occured:

```
"Could not complete the operation."
```

Now after deleting the first failover I'm unable to create another one using the same database...

Anyone got any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's by design. You cannot reuse the name until several days later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is indeed to be expected: one may reuse the instance name, but not right away. The instance name is unavailable for up to a week before it can be [reused](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#reuse).

However, one cannot replicate the second try: creating a failover with a different name. Here, the procedure does work and a differently named failover database is created successfully.

More detail on the gcloud commands or GUI menus steps followed might bring light on the matter.